# How to lock position of panel even the screen form is maximize?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have main form that has a header or banner under that is the navigation and under navigation i have panel where all forms will show when i click the button in navigation. My problem is the form is maximized when the other form show in that panel in my mainform the location of of boxes stay to orignal size and position.

[image: form inside the panel mainform]

I tried to anchor the boxes but i cant position them exactly, so i search po xycoordinates tool for windows but even using coordinates of tool provides different location.

[image: expected but maximized]

that image is the expected ouput but it is maximized and the boxes sticks.

Comment: Try putting controls into a panel.  Then put panel(s) into form.    You have better control of controls when they are in a panel than putting controls directly into a form.

Comment: That is a panel I just set the background Image. And the controls or boxes are inside of it

Comment: Specify which GUI framework you are using.

Comment: I don't know how to look for that, but I am using .NET FRAMEWORK 4.5

Comment: If maybe using WPF or Windows Forms. Please add the appropriate tag so the others can help you better.

Comment: Do you have a bunch of .xaml files? then you are using WPF. If you have any forms/controls with a subfile named .Designer.cs you are using winforms.

Comment: oh sorry, Im just using windows form